# Apache 3rd party libraries when running Django

Tags: django, apache2

I am using Apache2 to serve a Django app. The Django app uses Intel libraries with Numpy.  However, when Apache loads the Python scripts, it doesn't use the Intel libraries.

Here is what I have in `os.environ` within the script when Apache runs it:

```
{'LANG': 'C', 'APACHE_LOCK_DIR': '/var/lock/apache2', 'TZ': 'America/Chicago', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'mysite.settings', 'APACHE_RUN_USER': 'my_user', 'PWD': '/', 'APACHE_PID_FILE': '/var/run/apache2.pid', 'APACHE_RUN_DIR': '/var/run/apache2', 'APACHE_LOG_DIR': '/var/log/apache2', 'APACHE_RUN_GROUP': 'my_group', 'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'}
```

So Apache runs with permissions of `my_user`, but while `my_user` normally loads `.bashrc` on startup that adds all the necessary environmental variables, Apache doesn't do that.

So because LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not present, I get import errors.  It works when run as a normal user and as root.

I tried to add the following in `/etc/apache2/envvars`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/mic/coi/host-linux-release/lib:/opt/intel/mic/myo/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/mpirt/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/tbb/lib/intel64"
```

But that clearly doesn't work.

So my question is:
How do I add 3rd party libraries for Apache to use when running Django?

Comment: why not use nginx? faster, more secure and just pure awesome. if you need apache for certain things you can run both django and apache under nginx.

Comment: I wouldn't have this problem with nginx?  I am using apache2 because that is what was recommended on the django site.

Comment: Most likely you would not. On the Django site they state to try mod_wsgi first because that is probably more comfortable for majority of people coming from PHP. I however don't think its the best option. Nginx is much faster since it is so light weigh and I find configuring nginx is much easier than Apache.

Comment: Recently I write a blog post explaining the general process of deploying Django on nginx. Hopefully it can be helpful to you. I tried to explain all the high-level concepts and once you get them, Googling for code examples is much easier (or you can ask here on StackOverflow). http://blog.miki725.com/deploy-django-on-gevent-with-nginx/